# Getting error in Rest Api guest-cart. [POST] V1/guest-carts/{cart-id}/items

Tags: magento2

1.Created a guest cart (this will give me the cartID)-> POST: http://.../Magento2/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts

2. Get cart details-> GET: http://.../Magento2/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/{cartID}.
3. add items to cart-> POST: http://.../Magento2/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/{cartID}/items

Added in body part.
{
  "cartItem": {
    "item_id": 0,
    "sku": "string",
    "qty": 0
 }
}

**Getting Error :-**
{
  "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
  "parameters": {
    "fieldName": "cartId",
    "fieldValue": null
  },

Thanks in advance.

For ref. Testing in postman client & using  http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#/ link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add item to guest cart

[POST] http://.../Magento2/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/ - gives cart Id.

[POST]  http://.../Magento2/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/a03da1c69a5b1b57a405d05a31e16ce5/items – Adds an item to cart.

Body - 
{
  "cartItem": {
    "quote_id": "a03da1c69a5b1b57a405d05a31e16ce5",
    "sku": "Mobile1",
    "qty": 10
}
}

Comment: Can you verify that this works on magento 2.1?

Comment: @Mackelito The answer works on Magento 2.2

Answer (score 1):

Try using quote_id instead of cartId

Posting this

```
qty:1
quote_id:"75fc406b9aadbad6fe1b9a2df9881acd"
sku:"24-MB03"
```

to "V1/guest-carts/75fc406b9aadbad6fe1b9a2df9881acd/items"